# What software does Wikia use and can I have that for my own hosted Wiki?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

I want my own hosted Wiki so its fully under my control, but would like something as advanced as [**Wikia**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) rather than the plain, feature-lacking [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) style MediaWiki.

What software does Wikia use and can I have that for my own hosted Wiki? Is it just upgraded/added-on MediaWiki.

Comment: Other than asking the name of a program (well stack really I imagine) and how to get it, how exactly is this related to the act of programming?

Comment: Not Programming Related.

Comment: Nevertheless it is a good question. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find Wikia's customizations and extensions to MediaWiki [at their dev wiki](http://dev.wikia.com/wiki/Wikia_Developers_Wiki).

They keep most of their tweaked code in a publicly-accessible SVN server, linked there.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Wikia uses a modified version of the standard Mediawiki distribution that they've been augmenting over the years.

Their business model is to host Wikis (and generate ad revenue) but also to attract users with features not available in standard MediaWiki. I don't think they're offering the software for free, and I doubt that they're selling it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Wikia uses the latest version of the MediaWiki software (MediaWiki 1.13.4), but with many of the [extensions](http://traveller.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Version). The advanced features you see are their hard work at adding a "skin" (called Monaco) of css and javascript over the top. If you ask politely, they will give you a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Their source code is in a public GitHub repository.

If you want to download it and use it on your own go to the latest "release-*" branch.

https://github.com/Wikia/app